# How can I substitute an object in a python string ?

Tags: python, string

I have an object of class `Employee`.

```
#  For Example
>>> employee1 = Employee()
```

I need to substitute the object `employee1` in below expression. The expression will be dynamic

```
>>> expr = "object.basic_sal * 0.10 + 500"
```

For Example,

```
>>> employee1 = Employee()
>>> employee1.basic_sal = 10000
>>> expr = "object.basic_sal * 0.10 + 500"

>>> eval_expr(object=employee1, expression=expr)
1500
```

I could not find similar questions.
Please help me.

Comment: and why do you need that? why don't you create a function?

Comment: I think a function will more suitable. why not using function?

Comment: The expression will be variable. So I need to write each functions for each cases.
I just need like eval() function.

Comment: So, use eval, at your own risk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to interpolate values into strings:

```
expr = "{object.basic_sal} * 0.10 + 500".format(object=employee1)
```

To evaluate the expression you can use the [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function, although it is not generally recommended because of security risks.

```
result = eval(expr)
```